# NodeJS noob issue with mysql and async calls

Tags: node.js, node-mysql, node-async

I'm trying to build a simple Node app consisting of two files. One (main) file contains and exports a db connection (content of file index.js):

```
 const con = mysql.createConnection({
    host: process.env.DBHOST,
    user: process.env.DBUSER,
    password: process.env.DBPASS,
    database: process.env.DBSCHEMA,
    charset: 'utf8mb4'
});

module.exports = {
    getDBAccess: function(sqlString, callback) {
        con.connect(function(err) {
            if (err) throw err;

            // query to the database and get the records
            con.query(sqlString, function (err, recordset) {

                if (err) return callback(err)

                return callback(null, recordset);
            });
        });
    }
}
```

and in another file (process.js) i need to:

1. get data to a function
2. split data according to a regex
3. for each match (in loop) execute a db query to replace current value from the loop
4. return modified text

Code that should do things 1-4 looks like this (in process.js file):

```
function processHashtagsFromInput(text) {
        let regex = /#([^`~!@$%^&*\#()\-+=\\|\/\.,<>?\'\":;{}\[\]* ]+)/g; //find all hashtags

        do {
            match = regex.exec(text);
            if (match) {
                const updatePromises = [];
                updatePromises.push(get_hashtag(match[1], function(hi) {
                    let syntax = '#[' + hi + ']';
                    text = text.replace(match[0], syntax);
                }));

                await Promise.all(updatePromises);
            }
        } while (match);


        return text;
    }

function get_hashtag(tag, fnc) {
    let md5_val = md5(tag);
    let hash_id = -1;

    let query = "some_SELECT_query_here_searching_for_rows_with_matching_MD5_value";
    main_file.getDBAccess(query, function (err, rows, fields) {
        if (err) throw err;

        rows.forEach(function (row) {
            hash_id = row.id; //nevermind the loop, there's one or no result anyway
        });

        fnc(hash_id);
    });
}
```

The problem i'm having is that despite what i apply from various StackOverflow posts, i can't make sure

```
return text;
```

is executed only after *entire* loop is executed. I know it has to do with default async execution of the mysql but if i'm not concerned about the speed - how can i force my code to execute sequentially (loop -> query db -> process result -> loop -> ... return)?

Thanks!

**EDIT:**
I tried with this approach but idk how to make sure Promis ecan access outside variable called "text", that's the only problem heh

```
if (match) {
                
                new Promise( () => {
                    get_hashtag(match[1], function(hi) {
                        let syntax = '#[' + hi + ']';
                        text = text.replace(match[0], syntax);
                    })
                });
                
            }
```

Comment: processHashtagsFromInput() doesn't do anything async, so it's unnecessary complexity to add a promise array and Promise.all here. 

You could also consider using `mysql2/promise` if you want to work with async/await keywords instead of callbacks. Might be easier to start with.

Comment: Sorry, re-read your code and you should probably do it the other way around. First fetch all hashtags (if that is possible), build a lookup table of md5 hash and whatever you want to inject, and then use a regex to find hashtag, and a callback to replace it via the lookup table (see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace#specifying_a_function_as_a_parameter). Unless you have millions of hashtags, that would be way more performant.

Answer (score 0):

your `function processHashtagsFromInput(text)` is missing the keyword `async` ,
 `async function processHashtagsFromInput(text)` because you are using `await` without it

Comment: That didn't helped :(